# Replacing "\/" with "/" in php

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace, replaceall

I am trying to replace all occurences of `\/` in a string output in php with `/`, but it is not working..

Here is my code:

```
$output = str_replace("\\/", "/", $output);
echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

but I am still getting such strings in the output on the webpage, like:

```
https:\/\/img.xxxx.com\/images\/channel-resources\/1\/def\/43\/0\/1\/defintion.png
```

or  something like that:

```
https:\/\/img.yyyy.de\/images\/channel-resources\/1\/obchi\/43\/0\/1\/obchi_1.png
```

If I switch the order of the two functions like that:

```
$output = str_replace("\\/", "/", $output);
echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

I get the slashes written right, but the germans letters are appearing in a weird form, like: "\u00df" or "u00f6\u00df"... for example the world "große" would be written like "gro\u00dfe"

Anyone an idea to fix that? to get the german letters and the URIs written right? not like "https://img.xxxx.com/images/channel-resources/1/def/43/0/1/defintion.png"?

Comment: you're trying to replace a character with the same character?

Comment: try this `$output = str_replace("\/", "/", $output);`

Comment: tried it already before coming here.. got the same printed on the page! The problem is, when I try my code on http://phptester.net/ it works as I need it

Comment: @Cruiser no.. I am trying to replace the printed "\/" with "/", so that the URIs are valid

Comment: @KarimBelkhiria The code works.

Comment: Have you tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php?

Comment: @Karim, ok that must've been a typo you fixed then.

Comment: use json_decode($output,true), you will get without slash

Comment: Check this its working : https://eval.in/588682

Comment: `echo $str = str_replace('/', '', $str);`

Comment: @FrayneKonok you saw my edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong constant.

Use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` instead of `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` to prevent escaping the slashes in `json_encode()`.

You can specify both using `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

```
$output = str_replace("\\/", "/", $output);
echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: you're right! so that's fixed with the "\/" but I have the weird characters like that "\u00d" now in text, instead of the german letters like 'ö' and 'ä' and so on..

Comment: You can specify both using the bitwise or operator `|` like so: `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`, which should give you both. I'll edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: worked with the or operator! Thank you so much!!  But next problem.. I am not getting the DataTable displayed.. I will edit my post, with my javascript-code, so that you can see where could be the problem

Comment: @KarimBelkhiria If you have a new question, it's better to post a new question. Remember that Q&A's on this site are supposed to be useful to other people as well. Besides, it's better for your own reputation as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo $output and check it, I am almost sure it is the json_encode() you are using that adds the \ for you

Comment: I need the json_encode to get rid of such strings "\u00c4\u00b3" instead of german letters in the code.. It helped me getting the german letters.

Answer (score 0):

`\u00*` are Unicode letters.

Try this to parse into **html_entities**

```
$output = 'http:\/\/ßßüüää.com\/';
$output = str_replace("\\/", "/", $output);
$output = htmlentities($output, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8");
echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: I am gettiing an error with that "DataTables warning: invalid json response" and "null" is returned (echoed)